# Is translation of copyrighted material permitted?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, books-generally

Is there any violation in Halacha if someone translates copyrighted material to a dialect for the sole purpose of making it into a book so that people who do not know the dialect could benefit from it to get closer to Hashem?

How do Sefardim hold?

Comment: Are you speaking of translating a copyrighted book without the permission of its author? Isn't that forbidden by secular law? If yes, *dina d'malchuta dina* would forbid it halachically as well

Comment: I don't think the '*sole purpose.. closer to Hashem*' is going to make a difference to the *halachah*. This is a *Choshen Mishpat* question; good intentions won't change anything but your conscience.

Answer (score 3):

**businesshalacha.com** has 2 articles which would seem to touch on your question.
The first- titled "[Ownership of Mental Creations](https://www.businesshalacha.com/en/folder-money-matters/copyrights-and-patents)"  (scroll down to #2) writes:

> **Q: Does halacha recognize ownership of mental creations, such as Torah thoughts, professional techniques, computer programs or music works, beyond the physical entity of a book or disc?**
>
> A: This very fundamental question regarding copyright issues remains a significant dispute between the authorities.
>
> The **Maharsham** (2:202) explicitly maintains that a person does not have ownership over a professional technique he developed, because it is intangible. Thus, once a book or disc is sold, the creator cannot claim absolute ownership over the inherent content to prohibit copying it. This position is indicated also by the **Chasam Sofer** (C.M. #79; 41; 6:57) and other Gedolim who wrote approbations prohibiting others from reprinting Torah works on the basis of other reasons.
>
> On the other hand, the Shoe'el U'maishiv and others, including many contemporary authorities – e.g., **Rav Moshe Feinstein zt"l** (O.C. 4:40[19]) and **Rav Y.S. Eliyahiv zt"l** – maintain that a person has ownership of his mental creations. While the customer bought the book or disk, he did not buy the mental creation itself. Thus, according to this opinion, one who copies against the creator's will is stealing his mental creation.
>
> (See Emek Hamishpat, Zechuyos Yoztrim, Intro. pp. 1-3.)

In terms of whether copyright applies to Torah works (as your question seems to imply), **businesshalacha.com** addresses this as well in "[Ownership of Torah Works](https://www.businesshalacha.com/en/folder-money-matters/copyrights-and-patents)" (scroll down to #6):

> **Q: Is there any difference between the copyright of Torah works and other intellectual property, such as music or secular works?**
>
> A: The **Sho'el U'maishiv** (1:44) applies full ownership rights also to Torah thoughts.
>
> However, the Gemara (Nedarim 37a) states that, in principle, Torah teachings should be disseminated for free, just as Moshe taught Am Yisrael for free.
>
> Based on this, some authorities distinguish between the copyright of Torah works and other intellectual property. Even according to the opinion that a person has actual ownership of intellectual property, they maintain that a person has only limited ownership or rights in Torah works. **Beis Yitzchak** (Y.D. 2:75) restricts the copyright to the first printing, which allows the author to recoup his publishing costs. The Torah requires teaching Torah thoughts for free, but it does not require the additional effort of writing or publishing for free.
>
> Others compare the rights of Torah thoughts to tovas hana'ah (incidental benefit) of terumah, which allows incidental financial benefit through distributing the Torah thoughts.
>
> Regardless, other reasons for copyright – e.g., dina d'malchusa and common commercial practice – would apply equally to Torah works.
>
> (See Emek Hamishpat, Zechuyos Yotzrim ch. 6, 12)

To be safe: [**CYLOR**](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)